# No devices connected

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I'm trying to connect my laptop to Kinect. After running `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` I get the following message: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected.
I know this question has been asked many times, but I've tried all of the advice I found here and am running out of ideas. When I run `killall  XnSensorServer` I get no such process found and when I run `XnSensorServer` I get XnSensorServer: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenNI.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64. Could this be the issue? How can I fix it?

Best regards, Elizaveta

UPD

```
turtle@turtle-brain:~$ apt-cache policy libopenni0
libopenni0:
  Установлен: 1.5.4.0-7
  Кандидат:   1.5.4.0-7
  Таблица версий:
 *** 1.5.4.0-7 0
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
turtle@turtle-brain:~$ ldd /usr/lib/libopenni-sensor-primesense0/XnSensorServer
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff519eb000)
    libOpenNI.so.0 => /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so.0 (0x00007fde9cba8000)
    libXnFormats.so.0 => /usr/lib/libXnFormats.so.0 (0x00007fde9c981000)
    libXnDDK.so.0 => /usr/lib/libXnDDK.so.0 (0x00007fde9c729000)
    libXnDeviceSensorV2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libXnDeviceSensorV2.so.0 (0x00007fde9c484000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fde9c0bd000)
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007fde9bea6000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fde9bca2000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fde9ba83000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fde9b87b000)
    libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinyxml.so.2.6.2 (0x00007fde9b666000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fde9b361000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fde9b05b000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fde9ae45000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fde9ce51000)
    libXnCore.so.0 => /usr/lib/libXnCore.so.0 (0x00007fde9ac40000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so.8 (0x00007fde9a9eb000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007fde9a7d9000)
    libcgmanager.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcgmanager.so.0 (0x00007fde9a5be000)
    libnih.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih.so.1 (0x00007fde9a3a5000)
    libnih-dbus.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnih-dbus.so.1 (0x00007fde9a19b000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fde99f56000)
turtle@turtle-brain:~$ uname -a
Linux turtle-brain 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

When I run `dpkg-query --list |grep openni |awk '{print $2}' | xargs -d "\n" sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y` I get the following:

```
turtle@turtle-brain:~$ dpkg-query --list |grep openni |awk '{print $2}' | xargs -d "\n" sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово (reading package lists - ready)
Построение дерева зависимостей (building dependency trees) Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово (reading state information -ready) Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. (Some packages can't be installed)
Возможно, вы просите невозможного, или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming. (Maybe you request the impossible or use an unstable distributive version where the requested packages aren't installed or were deleted)
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам: (Following information might be useful to you) Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости: (packages that use unsatisfied dependencies)
libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0 : Конфликтует: libopenni-sensor libopenni-sensor-primesense0 : Конфликтует: libopenni-sensor (conflicting)
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты. (Can't fix the errors, you have broken packages held)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202836/no-devices-connected/) by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-10**:
The error about ELF class could certainly be contributing to your problem. It looks like you have a 64 bit version of libOpenNI.so, but your computer is a 32 bit machine. Did you install the `libopenni0` package from apt-get? If so, it could be that your sources are setup wrong.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-10**:
Please edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libopenni0` and `ldd /usr/lib/libopenni-sensor-primesense0/XnSensorServer` and `uname -a`

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-12**:
I guess I have installed it from apt-get. If this is the problem, how do I change my sources setup? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
Interestingly, the output of `uname -a` suggests you have a 64-bit machine, and your `apt-cache policy` command suggests that your sources are setup correctly. Let's try re-installing all of your openni packages from apt-get in case you've accidently installed some conflicting files without apt-get

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
I just used the following command to accomplish this reinstall `dpkg-query --list |grep openni |awk '{print $2}' | xargs -d "\n" sudo apt-get install --reinstall -y`

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
As another option, you could try using [freenect_launch](http://wiki.ros.org/freenect_launch) to run your Kinect instead of `openni_launch`

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-23**:
Those errors would be better presented by editing your original question. You have some conflicting packages; this could mean that you have installed openni packages from multiple places. You could also be running into issues that are documented: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/issues/171

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-23**:
When I run into package conflicts, I often turn towards aptitude instead of apt-get it is better at presenting solutions to these types of conflicts. Did you ever try `freenect_launch`?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2015-02-26**:
How did you install packages? You should not install `libopenni0` with apt-get but just `ros-indigo-openni-launch` and you will automatically get all dependencies...

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-02-27**:
`freenect_launch` works and I can get image from the camera, so that's great, thank you, Jarvis. But I would like to use kinect for building a map and I was hoping to use gmapping. When I run `roslaunch turtlebot_navigation gmapping_demo.launch` I get the same error about no devices connected.

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2015-02-27**:
Than you have to change/write your own launch file where you will start freenect_launch and remap topics properly...

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-03-02**:
Do you mean that I should change slam_gmapping_pr2.launch in gmapping package? Sorry, I'm a novice in this. How do I start freenect_launch in the launch file?

**Comment by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) on 2015-03-02**:
The best is to create your own package with lunch files. Everything about that is here: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch

**Comment by [Elizaveta.Elagina](https://answers.ros.org/users/21601/elizaveta.elagina/) on 2015-03-04**:
Thnak you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone else that has this issue...

Go to: http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8/

Scroll down to "Troubleshooting".  From there make sure you following the instructions on:

1. Installing the driver
2. Disable USB 3.0 via the BIOS (a little farther down the page)

This will fix most of the problems related to Kinect not working.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Silliman](https://answers.ros.org/users/20282/mark-silliman/) with karma: 81 on 2015-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-03-04**:
She definitely has package conflicts, and errors related to system architecture. The posted resource is excellent, but I'd be surprised if disabling USB 3.0 would fix any issues.

**Comment by [Mark Silliman](https://answers.ros.org/users/20282/mark-silliman/) on 2015-03-05**:
Thanks Jarvis.  We had a newer laptop with the identical error msg.  BIOS fixed it because the Kinect is incompatible with most 3.0 USBs as well as many newer 2.0 USBs which are compatible with 3.0.   The trick that the BIOS does is it effectively downgrades them all so the Kinect can work.